# Multi-Tenancy with Spring 3.2.X and EclipseLink/Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, eclipselink, multi-tenant

I have to implement Multi-Tenant Web application having following requirements

1. Single Table Multi-Tenancy : All tenant's data for particular entity will be stored in a single table with TENANT_DISCRIMINATOR (TENANT_ID) as a column in each table.
2. Some tables for example Master Countries, Masters... , I want it to be common for all tenants i.e In those table, there will not be a column like TENANT_DISCRIMINATOR (TENANT_ID) and still I want to access it seamlessly.
3. On request or maintenance reason, I want to move data of Tenant which is already a part of Single Table Multi-Tenancy to a separate database schema and a vice-a-versa by some admin configuration and my web app, on next request should be able to communicate with that updated schema/datasource.

Right now for single table for all tenants. I have used

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
```

and plugged a

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource
```

into that. I want to have flexibility over here which can read some configuration and help me to decide the same table/data-source or some different data-source.

First two points, I am able to fulfill with EclipseLink framework.

My questions are

1. Is it possible to implement point 3 using EclipseLink?
2. Can hibernate 3+ or 4+ help me to implement these ?

Any help will be a appreciated.

Comment: You will need to outline #3 in more detail, as moving data to another table and having users seemlessly access it is a difficult proposition.  What effect do you expect on users currently accessing the old table/application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipselink does have a remote command that forces the metadata to be refreshed on running factories such that the next EntityManager obtained will use the new metadata.  This might allow you to use customizers and/or a metadata repository to make changes to your tenant structure with an admin client and then push those changes to your running application.  See
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/DesignDocs/368490
and https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/CacheCoordination

Comment: Thanks Chris, What i want to do that if already running tenant tells us to change any information like new datasource or new database, than I want to do this some admin app without restarting my multi-tenant web app. Is it possible using EclipseLink?

Comment: Chris, it will be good if you explain with some example , if possible

Comment: Did you go through the docs and have specific questions?  refreshMetadata and the RCM command allow you to propogate new properties to running EntityManagerFactories such that the next EM obtained from them will use the new settings, while old ones will continue unchanged.  There is a demo at https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MySports but will require adapting it to get what you need.